# Groupby and filter output is producing different results

Tags: r, dplyr

Can someone help me understand what the grouping is doing here, please?
Why do these two produce two different grouped outputs? The top returns all grouped variables where `n() >1` in results A and outside of A category but just the A pairing while the bottom returns `n() > 1` here duplicates exist in only A.

Sample Data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,3,4,5,6,6),
                 Acronym = c('A','B','A','A','B','A','A')
                 )
```

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%# 
  filter(Acronym == 'A',n() > 1)

df %>% filter(Acronym == 'A') %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(n() > 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, rows with `Acroynm == "A"` are in the data frame and contribute to the row count `n()`.

In the second example, these rows are removed, and don't contribute to row count from `n()`.

Answer (score 1):

If we want the first case to return only 'ID' 6, use `sum` to get the count of 'A' values in `Acronym`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   filter(sum(Acronym == 'A') > 1)
```

As mentioned in the other post, it is just that `n()` is based on the whole group count and not on the number of 'A's.  If we are unsure about the `filter`, create a column with `mutate` and check the output

```
df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(ind = Acronym == 'A' & n() > 1)
# A tibble: 7 × 3
# Groups:   ID [5]
     ID Acronym ind  
  <dbl> <chr>   <lgl>
1     1 A       TRUE 
2     1 B       FALSE
3     3 A       FALSE
4     4 A       FALSE
5     5 B       FALSE
6     6 A       TRUE 
7     6 A       TRUE
```